# Regarding membership issue in vscode

Tags: karate, membership

I am using Karate with vscode it was working fine but yesterday onwards I got issue to login on karatelabs.in to run test cases and get min Plus membership, is it paid now I am bit confused? Please help me here.

I am trying to run the test cases in vscode with karate extension but now getting issue to login and get plus membership.as it was working fine from long time so is it paid now?

Comment: yes the karate vs code extension is paid now

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas ,So how can we use now in vscode any guidance if we don’t want to use Java

Comment: it is possible to run tests on the command-line using the standalone-jar, npm or jbang: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Other-Runtime-Options